# Switching to ViewController (on storyboard)

Tags: objective-c, xcode5

I am attempting to make my application switch from one view to anther and then have a back button. I had no trouble with the first step but now I am trying to go back to my main view controller.

I have tried this code:

## 1

```
UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main.storyboard" bundle:nil];
ViewController *main = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ViewController"];
[main setModalPresentationStyle:UIModalPresentationFullScreen];
[self presentModalViewController:main animated:YES];
```

And also:

## 2

```
UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main.storyboard" bundle:nil];
ViewController *mainView = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ViewController"];
[mainView setModalPresentationStyle:UIModalPresentationFullScreen];
[self presentViewController:mainView animated:YES completion:NULL];
```

But neither methods work correctly. With method one I get an error on the last line `'presentModalViewController:animated:' is deprecated: first deprecated in iOS6.0`
As for the second method, it just plain doesn't work. I can load the application but as soon as I hot my back button it crashes with:

```
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000101947495 __exceptionPreprocess + 165
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00000001016a699e objc_exception_throw + 43
    2   UIKit                               0x000000010070d2b7 +[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:bundle:] + 542
    3   Swindler                            0x0000000100001827 -[SecondViewController backButton:] + 103
    4   UIKit                               0x0000000100254f06 -[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:] + 80
    5   UIKit                               0x0000000100254eb4 -[UIApplication sendAction:toTarget:fromSender:forEvent:] + 17
    6   UIKit                               0x0000000100331880 -[UIControl _sendActionsForEvents:withEvent:] + 203
    7   UIKit                               0x0000000100330dc0 -[UIControl touchesEnded:withEvent:] + 530
    8   UIKit                               0x000000010028bd05 -[UIWindow _sendTouchesForEvent:] + 701
    9   UIKit                               0x000000010028c6e4 -[UIWindow sendEvent:] + 925
    10  UIKit                               0x000000010026429a -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 211
    11  UIKit                               0x0000000100251aed _UIApplicationHandleEventQueue + 9579
    12  CoreFoundation                      0x00000001018d6d21 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 17
    13  CoreFoundation                      0x00000001018d65f2 __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 242
    14  CoreFoundation                      0x00000001018f246f __CFRunLoopRun + 767
    15  CoreFoundation                      0x00000001018f1d83 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 467
    16  GraphicsServices                    0x0000000103abef04 GSEventRunModal + 161
    17  UIKit                               0x0000000100253e33 UIApplicationMain + 1010
    18  Swindler                            0x0000000100001e43 main + 115
    19  libdyld.dylib                       0x0000000101fdf5fd start + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
(lldb)
```

Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want to back button, instead of presenting the view controller use push method so that it will give you the back navigation button automatically

```
[self.navigationController pushViewController:mainView animated:YES];
```

else add the UIBarbuttonItem in your second view controller in the storyboard manually and in that button target method call

```
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
```